# Reading integers from text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read integers from a **text** file but I failed. 
(It fails to read even the first integer)

```
public void readFromFile(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File to load game was not found");
    }
}
```

The error I get is: NoSuchElementException.
The file looks like this:

```
N,X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3
```

While n equals 3 in this example.

I call this method a in the main method like this:

```
readFromFile("file.txt");
```

Comment: The provided input has no integers present, hence the `NoSuchElementException`...

Comment: In a text file **N** = "N" as string as does "X1", "Y1", etc. There are no integers in a text file.

Comment: Please be aware that it is a best practice to insert the line: 'scanner.close();' into a finally block. try{} catch(){}, finally {scanner.close();} the finally is responsible of free the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you would like to display only the integers after separating them from the string. If that is the case, I would suggest you to use BufferedInputStream.

```
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))){
        String input = br.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length()- 1; i++){
            if(isNumeric(input.charAt(i))){

                // replace the Sysout with your own logic
                   System.out.println(input.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

where isNumeric can be defined as follows:

```
private static boolean isNumeric(char val) {
    return (val >= 48 && val <=57);
}
```

Comment: I thought of reading it as a line, and then scan the string. but isn't there another way?

Comment: Another suggestion that occurred to me was to design your own custom inputReader. But hasNext() will have to be implemented to achieve this and I feel that could really be an overkill.

Comment: By the way, Scanner is pretty slow. If what you mentioned in the question is a sample file input and your actual file is fairly large, I would suggest you to go for BufferedReader method

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner`uses whitespace as the default delimiter. You can change that with `useDelimiter` See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html